# Dropdown onclick isn't getting called when item selected in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The onlick event handler isn't getting called when I select dropdown item.

I am generating dropdown in a loop in `componentDidMount()` and passing event handler function **"showDataTypeName"** to `onclick` while generating dropdown but for some reason its not getting called. Any idea why this is failing?

Below is my component where I am generating dropdown

```
export class GenerateParams extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataTypeName: "Select Type",
            rows: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let dataTypes = [];
        let content = this.state.rows.slice();    
        if(typeof this.props.apiPropertiesSuccess != 'undefined' && this.props.apiPropertiesSuccess.size > 0){
            this.props.apiPropertiesSuccess.map((type, i) => {
                dataTypes.push(<li key={type.get('id')}><a onClick = {this.showDataTypeName(type.get('id'), type.get('name'))}> {type.get('name')} </a></li>)
            });
        }


        for(let i=0; i < this.props.params.length; i++){
            content.push(<div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <TextInput size="medium" value={this.props.params[i]} readOnly/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="dropdown">
                        <button className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{this.state.dataTypeName}
                            <span className="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                            {dataTypes}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>)
        }

        this.setState({rows:content})
    }
    showDataTypeName = (id, name) => {
        console.log("id, name", id, name)
        this.props.handleDataTypes(id, name);
        this.setState({
            dataTypeName: name
        });
    }

    render(){
        const {params, apiPropertiesSuccess} = this.props;     

        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.rows}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Note: Accepting xadm's answer because his solution was posted first. Thanks to @UtkarshPramodGupta and @anshul as well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the simplest solution (react docs): `this.showDataTypeName = this.showDataTypeName.bind(this)` in constructor

If you prefer using arrow function (automatic binding) you can use:
`onClick={ () => this.showDataTypeName(type.get('id'), type.get('name')) }`

But keep in mind that binding in render is not the optimal for performance reasons.

Comment: I no need to bind function/object because I am using arrow function.

Comment: in map, not in onclick

Comment: you don't ;) you have `onClick = {this.showDataTypeName`

arrow fn would look like
`onClick={ () => this.showDataTypeName (....) }`

Comment: Hey sorry xadm. placing () => worked for me. Kindly put this as an answer I will accept it

Comment: 'Nice' - you could accept it, `it was a solution`, not first answer alone but as a thread (with comments). It's also a cleaner, more readable, simply better than binding in render/onClick (upvoted?) and possibly better (not optimal, not better than accepted one) than using arrow function in onClick. Better than 2 other solutions and downvoted??

Comment: Agree with you xadm. yours was first solution and it was a comment but your answer was not modified as like what you posted in comment. I never down voted your solution I only upvoted your comment and answer but other people down voted it seems. I haven't accepted your answer because the solution is in comment but not in answer. A comment cannot be accepted as an answer right

Comment: Thanks, IMHO both solutions (first answer and comment) was right and constructor binding is a bit better ;)
I like @AnshulBansal solution, too.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling onclick the right way. Below is the right code:

```
<a onClick = {this.showDataTypeName.bind(this, type.get('id'), type.get('name'))}>
```

Comment: I no need to bind showDataTypeName when it is already an arrow function. It is working fine now after adding "() =>". <a onClick = {() => this.showDataTypeName(type.get('id'), type.get('name'))}> {type.get('name')} </a>. xadm comment is correct

Comment: It's not about binding it. It's about that onClick handler takes the name of the function and not its return value. In your code, you are executing the function on the line itself and that would assign the return value of the `showDataTypeName` function and not the function itself. Just try to do it the way I have suggested and It would work I promise. :)

Comment: I agree with that but just placing "() =>" in onClick = {() => this.showDataTypeName(type.get('id'), type.get('name'))} without binding working for me.

Comment: Yeah, that is also one way to do that if you don't wanna use bind. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your function as below.

```
showDataTypeName = (id, name) => () => {
        console.log("id, name", id, name)
        this.props.handleDataTypes(id, name);
        this.setState({
            dataTypeName: name
        });
    }
```

> Edit

A better approach to have performance improvement, would be to bind the click handler to the `ul` element and make use of event propagation to handle the click function. I have updated the code to reflect the same.

```
export class GenerateParams extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataTypeName: "Select Type",
            rows: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let dataTypes = [];
        let content = this.state.rows.slice();    
        if(typeof this.props.apiPropertiesSuccess != 'undefined' && this.props.apiPropertiesSuccess.size > 0){
            this.props.apiPropertiesSuccess.map((type, i) => {
                dataTypes.push(
                    <li key={type.get('id')} id={type.get('id')} name=type.get('name')>
                    {type.get('name')}
                </li>);
            });
        }


        for(let i=0; i < this.props.params.length; i++){
            content.push(<div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <TextInput size="medium" value={this.props.params[i]} readOnly/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="dropdown">
                        <button className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{this.state.dataTypeName}
                            <span className="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul className="dropdown-menu" onClick={this.showDataTypeName}>
                            {dataTypes}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>)
        }

        this.setState({rows:content})
    }
    showDataTypeName = (event) => {
        let id = event.target.id;
        let name = event.target.name;
        console.log("id, name", id, name)
        this.props.handleDataTypes(id, name);
        this.setState({
            dataTypeName: name
        });
    }

    render(){
        const {params, apiPropertiesSuccess} = this.props;     

        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.rows}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you think this '  = (id, name) => () => ' makes sense ? ... Calling an arrow function to call an arrow function  ?

Comment: It is working fine now after adding "() =>". <a onClick = {() => this.showDataTypeName(type.get('id'), type.get('name'))}> {type.get('name')} </a>

Comment: @HemadriDasari , even though it works you should avoid using arrow functions in the render functions. Refer this -> https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36

Comment: @AnshulBansal thanks for pointing me to the article. You used two arrows isn't that arrow function?

Comment: @HemadriDasari, yes it uses arrow function but `not inside the render ` function per se . The two arrow functions which I have used is used to create a closure. In simple terms the first function returns an anonymous function which gets called later on when click action is performed. This is another way to use arrow functions when we need to pass arguments to it. @l4b0mb4  :)

Comment: Okey understood. Great

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify `onClick` event on button click

```
<div className="dropdown">
    <button onClick={() => console.log('yeah')} className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{this.state.dataTypeName}
                                <span className="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                            {dataTypes}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I already have onClick handler to a tag when I am pushing to dataTypes. It is working fine now after adding "() =>". <a onClick = {() => this.showDataTypeName(type.get('id'), type.get('name'))}> {type.get('name')} </a>